# Akka/Scala detect closed TCP connection?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to write a TCP server using Akka and Scala, which will instantiate actors and stop the actors when a client connects and disconnects respectively. I have a TCP binding actor,

```
 class Server extends Actor{
   import Tcp._
   import context.system

   IO(Tcp) ! Bind(self, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9595))

   def receive = {

     case Bound(localAddress) =>
       println("Server Bound")
       println(localAddress)

     case CommandFailed(_: Bind) => context stop self

     case Connected(remote, local)=>
       val handler = context.system.actorOf(Props[ConnHandler])
       val connection = sender()
       connection ! Register(handler)
   }
 }
```

The above instantiates a TCP listener on `localhost:9595` and registers handler actors to each connection.

I then have the `receive` def in my `ConnHandler` class defined as such, abbreviated with `...` where the code behaves correctly.

```
case received => {...}
case PeerClosed => {
    println("Stopping")
    //Other actor stopping, cleanup.
    context stop self
}
```

(See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io-tcp.html for the docs I used to write this - it uses more or less the same code in the `PeerClosed` case)

However, when I close the socket client-side, the actor remains running, and no "Stopping" message is printed.

I have no nearby configured non-Windows machines to test this on, since I believe this to do with me running on Windows because after googling around, I found a still open bug - https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/17122 - which refers to some Close events being missed on Windows-based systems.

Have I made a silly error in my code, or would this be part of the bug linked above?

Although I could write in a case for `Received(data)` that would close the connection, however, a disconnect caused by the network disconnecting or something would leave the server in an unrecoverable state, requiring the application to be restarted since it would leave a secondary, shared actor in a state that says the client is still connected, and thus, the server would reject further connections from that user.

Edit:

I've worked around this by adding a watchdog timer actor that has a periodic action that fires after some amount of time. The `ConnHandler` actor will reset the watchdog timer every time an event happens on the connection. Although not ideal, it does what I want to do.

Answer (score -1):

Edit 12/9/2016:
ConnHandler will receive a PeerClosed message even when a client Unexpectedly disconnect.